# Unity 3D: Send data from client to client

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, ip, client, rpc

I'm trying to send data from client to client but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Unitys MasterServer. It works fine when i'm sending data from server to client and client to server.

I'm sending data with RPC. Is it possible to send data from client to client or do I have to rewrite my code so I send an RPC call from client 1 to server, and then a new RPC call from server to client 2?

Here I call the RPC function:

networkView.RPC("UpdateBombIncoming", playerPurple);

Here's my RPC:

```
[RPC]
void UpdateBombIncoming(){
    Debug.Log ("Bomb is incoming");
    bombIncoming = true;
}
```

Here's my Network code:

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {

```
public int maxNumberOfPlayers = 3;
public int port = 25002;
public int playerID;
public NetworkPlayer playerBlue;        // Server
public NetworkPlayer playerPurple;
public NetworkPlayer playerGreen;
public int playerColor;                 // 1: blue, 2: purple, 3: green
public Font myFont;
public int playerCount;

private SceneManager sceneManager;
private bool showPlayersOnGUI;

string registeredGameName = "Bomba_Alpha";
bool isRefreshing = false;
float RefreshRequestLength = 3.0f;
HostData[] hostData;

void Awake(){


}

void Start(){
    sceneManager = GetComponent<SceneManager>();
}


 void Update(){

    Debug.Log("Blue Player connected from " + playerBlue.ipAddress + ":" + playerBlue.port);
    Debug.Log("Purple Player connected from " + playerPurple.ipAddress + ":" + playerPurple.port);
    Debug.Log("Green Player connected from " + playerGreen.ipAddress + ":" + playerGreen.port);
    Debug.Log("Players connected to server " + playerCount);

    // When player is connected to server, show player on GUI
    if(Network.isServer){
        // Show players on GUI
        showPlayersOnGUI = true;
    }

    else if(Network.isClient){
        // Show players on GUI
        showPlayersOnGUI = true;
    }

}


private void StartServer(){
    Network.InitializeServer (maxNumberOfPlayers, port, false);
    MasterServer.RegisterHost(registeredGameName, "Bomba Alpha", "Test of TMB_server");
}

void OnServerInitialized(){
    Debug.Log ("Server has been initialized!");
    Debug.Log("Player " + playerCount + " connected from " + Network.player.ipAddress + ":" + Network.player.port);
    // Set server as playerBlue
    playerBlue = Network.player;
}

void OnMasterServerEvent(MasterServerEvent masterServerEvent){
    if(masterServerEvent == MasterServerEvent.RegistrationSucceeded){
        Debug.Log("Registration Successful!");
    }
}

public IEnumerator RefreshHostList(){
    Debug.Log ("Refreshing...");
    MasterServer.RequestHostList (registeredGameName);      // Get servers from MasterServer with 'our' name
    float timeStarted = Time.time;
    float timeEnd = Time.time + RefreshRequestLength;


    // Contínuelly update hostData
    while (Time.time < timeEnd) {
        hostData = MasterServer.PollHostList();                 // pull down the requested server
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    }

    // Check if there is no servers
    if (hostData == null || hostData.Length == 0) {
        Debug.Log ("No active servers have been found");
    }

    else{
        Debug.Log(hostData.Length + " server(s) found");
    }
}


void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player) {
    playerCount++;

    if(Network.player == player){
        Debug.Log ("Hey!");

    }

    if (playerCount == 2){
        playerPurple = player;
        Debug.Log ("I'm purple!");

    }

    // Set 2nd client as playerGreen
    else if (playerCount == 3){
        playerGreen = player;
    }

    if(Network.isServer){
        Debug.Log ("Colors are updating!");

        networkView.RPC("UpdateColors", RPCMode.Others, playerBlue, playerPurple, playerGreen, playerCount);
    }

    Debug.Log("Player " + playerCount + " connected from " + player.ipAddress + ":" + player.port);
}

void OnPlayerDisconnected(){
    playerCount--;
}


// On GUI is for testing and will not exist in the final game
public void OnGUI(){

    if (sceneManager.currentScene == 3){

        // Start server
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(150f,100f,300f,150f), "Start new server")){
            StartServer();
        }

        // Refresh server list
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(150f,250f,300f,150f), "Refresh server list")){
            StartCoroutine("RefreshHostList");
        }

        if (hostData != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < hostData.Length; i++){
                if(GUI.Button(new Rect(150f ,400f + (110f * i),300f,150f), hostData[i].gameName))
                {
                    Network.Connect(hostData[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Show list of players connected to the server
        if (showPlayersOnGUI) {

            GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();
            myStyle.font = myFont;

            GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 700, 200, 20), ("Other players connected:"), myStyle);

            if (Network.player == playerBlue){
                GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 600, 200, 20), ("You are BLUE player"), myStyle);

                if(playerCount == 1){
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 750, 200, 20), ("- none -"), myStyle);
                }
                if(playerCount >= 2){
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 750, 200, 20), ("Purple player"), myStyle);
                }
                if(playerCount == 3){
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 800, 200, 20), ("Green Player"), myStyle);
                }
            }

            else if (Network.player == playerPurple){
                GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 600, 200, 20), ("You are PURPLE player"), myStyle);

                if(playerCount >= 2){
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 750, 200, 20), ("Blue player"), myStyle);
                }
                if(playerCount == 3){
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 800, 200, 20), ("Green Player"), myStyle);
                }
            }

            else if (Network.player == playerGreen){
                GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 600, 200, 20), ("You are GREEN player"), myStyle);

                if(playerCount == 3){
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 750, 200, 20), ("Blue player"), myStyle);

                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 800, 200, 20), ("Purple Player"), myStyle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



void UpdatePlayersOnNetwork(){
    if (Network.player == playerBlue) {
        Debug.Log("I'm player BLUE");
        networkView.RPC("UpdateBluePlayer", RPCMode.Others, Network.player);

    }
    if (Network.player == playerPurple) {
        Debug.Log("I'm player PURPLE");
        networkView.RPC("UpdatePurplePlayer", RPCMode.Others, Network.player);

    }
    if (Network.player == playerGreen) {
        Debug.Log("I'm player GREEN");
        networkView.RPC("UpdateGreenPlayer", RPCMode.Others, Network.player);

    }
}



// -------- RPC sends data via network --------

// Update player-color connections
[RPC]
void UpdateColors(NetworkPlayer blue, NetworkPlayer purple, NetworkPlayer green, int players){

    Debug.Log ("Colors are updated");

    playerBlue = blue;
    playerPurple = purple;
    playerGreen = green;
    playerCount = players;
    //Debug.Log ("Colors have been updated!");
}
```

}

Thanks

Moeskjaer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of implementing your own RPC system in C#, you'll need to rewrite your code to "bounce" RPCs off of the server.

In Unity's networking model, the clients are all connected to the server but not to each other. Any state changes the clients cause is sent to other clients through the server.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So does that mean I have to send an RPC from client 1 to the server and then send a new RPC from server to client 2? Or could I maybe use RPCmode.others and send an int and differentiate between players with if-sentences?

Comment: I found a solution. When clients connects to the server, they get a unique 'int playerNumber'. When sending data from a client (or server) I just use RPCMode.others and set an 'int player' parameter corresponding to the playerNumber of the player I want to receive it. In the RPC function I only run the code "if (player == playerInt)"

Comment: Yup! That's similar to what I do, though I use the GUID of each player since that's consistent between sessions. If you use the Master Server to connect players, you can also use the stored GUIDs to perform host migration.